# Iterate over python dict based on a csv column which is grouped

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pymongo

I have attached an csv file. I have written a python script which reads the csv file and iterates over a data frame and process the contents of csv and insert it into mongoDB.

Right now, all data is getting inserted into the DB.

Is there a way to iterate over python dict and only take first 10 ranks data (group rank column), this column is grouped as you can see in attached img.

[image]

```
file = request.files['file']
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")



df = pd.read_csv(file)

final_dict = {}
for row in df.iterrows():
    cluster_name = row[1][1]
    print(cluster_name)
    if cluster_name not in final_dict.keys():
        final_dict[cluster_name] = {}
        final_dict[cluster_name]["queries"] = []
        final_dict[cluster_name]["queries"].append(
  {"cluster_name": row[1][0], "cluster_rank": row[1][1], 
   "cluster_size": row[1][2]})
           
    else:
        final_dict[cluster_name]["queries"].append(
            {"cluster_name": row[1][0], "cluster_rank": row[1][1], "cluster_size": row[1][2]})



db = client["db_name"]

for key in final_dict:
    db.testing.insert_one(final_dict[key])
```

Comment: Can you please put in a programable version of your data as well as a programable version of your expected results? Your question is not very clear on your intentions.

Comment: Finally, what should be inserted into the DB, for this example?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the python script

Comment: @MohammadRifatArefin, I want that only first 10 ranked columns should be inserted. Right now lets say if sheet has 1 to 100 ranked, all columns are getting inserted but I want only first 10 ranked should be inserted

Comment: What are the ranks? I believe that is part of the confusion? You have a group rank column, but it is the exact same throughout the entire screen shot. Ranks 1 - 100 means nothing if we don't understand what the ranks are supposed to be unless you simply want everything in the group rank column that the number is <= 100

Comment: In the csv, Demo Group has rank 1, Test has rank 2, Live has rank 3, real has rank 4.Like this there is rank corresponding to each group name. As you can see first 5 rows have same rank (1) which is mapped to group name Demo.
My use case is I want to only store records till rank 10. 
Is this clear now ?
Sry for description

Comment: I put an answer below let me know if thats what your needing.

Answer (score 0):

To only get rows that are equal to or less than 10 in the group rank you can use a loc option

```
df = df.loc[df['group rank'] <= 10]
df
```

Comment: I have added this in for loop but didn't work


if cluster_name not in final_dict.keys() and df.loc[df['group rank'] <= 10]: